# Way to implement multi threading in non spring managed class

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, performance

For a single API call, I need to execute code in 4 threads, process it and return the response. I have implemented this using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as below:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
executor.setThreadNamePrefix("customThread-");
executor.initialize();
return executor;
```

The above `executor` I am creating for each API request and calling `shutdown()` at the end. After that, somewhere I read that its costly to create `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` object for each request.

Anyways, with above code the performance is not good. Kindly suggest the better way to implement this.

FYI, I am executing this code in **final non Spring managed class**. So, could not create bean of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and autowire it.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the singleton pattern. In that way you create your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ` once and you can request the instance where needed to submit tasks. More info in this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton).

Comment: In singleton pattern, at a time a single thread can access the method to get `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` . Will that be helpful in multithreaded application?

Comment: You absolutely do not want to be spinning up executors from incoming requests. Instead, you would pre-allocate this pool, and allow the requests to submit tasks/callables/runnables to the executor. Where you store this is up to you really, just ensure it isn't being remade.

Comment: With regards to the Singleton you would indeed not want that creation of the instance can occur by multiple thread. But after creation there's no need to synchronize. Maybe the creation can be overcome by using a static block.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of an atypical implementation, but you could use a static block to create the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and then submit tasks to it as you please.

```
public class ThreadPoolTaskExecutorSingleton {
    private static ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    static {
        executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("customThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        // This happens during loading of your class so you will only have one ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.
    }

    public static ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getInstance() {
        return executor;
    }

}
```

I created a working example in this [repository](https://github.com/Lefeverw/stackoverflow-threadpoolexecutor-static-block).

Comment: Sure. I will implement this way and try performance test.

Comment: any suggestion on pool size and queue capacity?

Comment: I'm wondering if you should configure it yourself or use something preconfigured like `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`. One of the problem with configuring yourself is that if you add more than 100 tasks (the queue size), you will get `TaskRejectedException`. So you need to know very well what you're doing. I think the other option is in that sense more user-friendly.